# Query to find mutual likes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has the id of a particular person and id of the person he likes.

Likes

```
(p1,p2)
id1,id2
id2,id1
id3,id4
id3 id5
```

expected output

```
id1,id2
```

I have to remove duplicates also meaning id1,id2 to be returned once.

It is a exercise question.

```
select hh.id, hh.name, hh.grade as gr
     , hh.id2, kk.name, kk.grade as gr1
  from ( select id, id2, grade, name 
           from highschooler ab 
              , Likes cd 
          where ab.id = cd.id1 ) hh 
     , highschooler kk 
 where hh.id2 = kk.id
```

This query returns something like this

> student id,student name,student grade,friend student likes,friend name,friend grade

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: Show the code you've written so far to try and solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it joining on itself:

```
SELECT p.p1, p.p2
FROM Likes p
    INNER JOIN Likes p2 ON 
        p.p1=p2.p2 AND 
        p.p2=p2.p1 AND 
        p.p1<p2.p1
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7530d/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the nicest way to do this is with a `group by`.  In SQL Server, this requires using a `case` statement:

```
with l as (
    select (case when p1 < p2 then p1 else p2 end) as pfirst,
           (case when p1 < p2 then p2 else p1 end) as psecond
    from likes
   )
select pfirst, psecond
from l
group by pfirst, psecond
having count(*) = 2
```

If you have duplicates in the original data, then the having clause should be:

```
having count(distinct p1) = 2
```